# Cannot call method 'getPosition' of undefined

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, maps

i had a problem with Google Maps API. Google return error to me: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getPosition' of undefined. In this code:

```
function center_map(current) {
        var default_image_path = js_load_parameters.theme_default_path;
        map.setCenter(markers[current].getPosition());
        for(i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
            markers[i].setIcon(default_image_path+'/layout/images/marker_map_1.png');
        }
        markers[current].setIcon(default_image_path+'/layout/images/marker_map_1_act.png');
        current_location = current;
    }
```

Comment: Well, of course, that would indicate that markers[current] is evaluating to undefined.  Now, is this your code or is this part of the API library?

Comment: What is the value of current?  Does markers[current] exist?

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `current`? Is markers[current] defined? (probably not)
 
Here `markers[current]` is coming as undefined.

Add console log for both `current` and `markers` and see what are the values getting printed.

**Make sure you defined markers and count.**